# JQuery/Javascript checking dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

i m working on a web application, which i got two dropdown in one page.

```
<div id="A">
<select>
    <option value="">please select</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="">please select</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Now, i wanna make both dropdown mandatory to be selected(apart from "please select"), or user cant go any further.
here is my jquery code.

```
        var error=0;
        var selected_option = $('#A>select option:selected');
        $('#A').each(function() {
            if(!$('#A select').selected){
                error++;
            }
        });
        if (error>0) {
            alert('Choose the bloody option');
            return false;
        }
```

So far, the actual result is **Alert message** works fine, **mandatory select part** works fine. However, even i select from both, i still got alert and stuck. Thinking maybe its my `if condition` set inproperly. Please, someone give me a help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Change selected for val() to get the value of select.

```
 if(!$('#A select').val()){
```

Comment: will not work because there are multiple select elements... it will check only the first select element

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var valid = $('#A select').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).val()) == ''
}).length == 0

if(!valid){
    alert('not selected')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5DSuW/)

Another version

```
if ($('#A select').has('option:selected[value=""]').length > 0) {
    console.error('not selected')
}else {
    console.log('valid')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5g6Ta/)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one here is another way to achieve what you want

```
$('#A select').each(function() {
   if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != 'please select'){
       //do here your action
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $('#A select').each(function() {
      if($(this).find('option:selected').text() == 'please select'){
         error++;
      }
  });
```

Comment: will not work because there are multiple select elements... it will check only the first select element

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3BZED/)

```
 var selected_option = $('#A>select option:selected');
 $('#check').click(function () {
     var error = 0;
     $('#A select').each(function () {
         if ($(this).val() == '') {
             error++;
         }
     });
     if (error > 0) {
         alert('Choose the bloody option');
         return false;
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
var errors = 0;
$("#A select").each(function(){
if($(this).find("option:selected").is(":eq(0)")){
        errors++;
}
});

if(errors>0){ alert('error!'); }
```